# Where has the Groovy documentation gone?

Tags: groovy, javadoc, groovydoc

When I search Groovy javadocs (groovydocs, whatever) I find it in Google, but they all redirect to a kind of Groovy splash page saying how good Groovy is. For example, when I search "groovy uribuilder api" the link reads:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/URIBuilder.html

but that link redirects to:

http://beta.groovy-lang.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/URIBuilder.html

I can look at Google's cached version to get the real API documentation, but I'm worried that at some point this will disappear and I'll be stranded with half-finished Groovy code and no documentation. Is there a new root for Groovy documentation hosted anywhere?

Thank you

Update: the docs have reappeared, but the answers are nonetheless good info.

Comment: One of the [5 despots for Groovy](https://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/groovy/members) is setting up an alternative website to take control of Groovy away from the other 4, hence the redirect. He also posts notifications about Groovy on his personal website instead of the Groovy users mailing list, and for the past year has been soliciting subscribers to a weekly mailout he controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root I've been using is http://beta.groovy-lang.org/api.html

I believe this change happened over the past couple months, as I was using groovy.codehause.org documentation before.

Comment: the problem is not finding the new root but the lack of docs on the new site (e.g. OP mentions http-builder)

Comment: It's too bad, the format is much more puffy as compared to the old documentation. But thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

There are now broken links strewn all over the web (and elsewhere). I've resorted to using the wayback machine -- https://archive.org/web/

Of course, if you're following a link from google you can pull up the cached version.

Answer (score 1):

Currently visible is the new beta version of the page. But it is incomplete and not supposed to be online at the moment. It is only, because Codehaus is currently having some major issues. This will change in the very near future